# Вывод элементов из односвязного списка

Tags: c++, список

Создала линейный односвязный список. Как его вывести?

```
 struct Data
{   int a;
};

struct List
{   Data d;
List *next;
};




int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    List *u = NULL;
    // 1 uzel
    u = new List; // obyavlenie 
    u->d.a = 3;  
    u->next = NULL; // ukazatel na sled element
    // dlya udobstva sozd peremennuyu-ukazatel kotoraya hranit adress posl elementa
    List *x;
    // 2 uzel
    x = u;
    x->next = new List;
    x = x->next;
    x->d.a = 5;
    x->next = NULL;
    // 
    List *c;
    // 3 uzel
    c = x;
    c->next = new List;
    c = c->next;
    c->d.a = 1;
    c->next = NULL;
    //
    List *b;
    // 4 uzel
    b = c;
    b->next = new List;
    b = b->next;
    b->d.a = 9;
    b->next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не буду разбираться, как вы вводили - вопрос ведь не как создать, а как вывести? Но если там все верно, то просто идем по списку.

```
struct Data
{   
    int a;
};

struct List
{   
    Data d;
    List *next;
};
```

Если указатель на первый элемент списка - `List*head`, то выглядит это примерно так:

```
while(head)
{
    cout << head->d.a << endl; // Вывод текущего элемента
    head = head->next;         // Переход к следующему
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас) все вышло:)

Comment: может быть Вы еще подскажите, как поменять местами максимальный и минимальный элементы?)

Comment: Ну, надо найти указатели на предыдущие им. Допустим, это `p1` и `p2`. Потом просто обмениваете значения `p1->next` и `p2->next`, а также `p1->next->next` и `p2->next->next` - вобщем, нарисуйте на бумажке схемку со стрелочками, и все станет понятно :)